Rlang Version 1.1.4 for r Version 4.2.0
My problem:
I want to install the package "rlang" but i get the error message "rlang 1.1.3 is used but rlang >= 1.1.4 is needed". I have the r version 4.2.0.
what can i do to install the rlang package with version 1.1.4?
What i tried:
I Tried installing the package again and used detach(rlang) before. This is how it looked like:
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.4.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")

Have you tried update.packages()?

@Eonema If install.packages() doesn’t work, update.packages() won’t either. (In fact, that function is basically useless anyway.)

Instead of detach(), which does not unload the package (even once you fixed the syntax), use unloadNamespace().1
Then, to install the package, use the package name, not a URL.
The following should do the trick:
unloadNamespace('rlang')
install.packages('rlang')

However, this may still fail if ‘rlang’ is being used by other loaded packages. A better, more reliable, simpler way is to instead restart R to start from a clean slate before running install.packages('rlang').

1 You could also use detach('package:rlang', unload = TRUE) but that’s a lot more to write, and there’s no advantage over using unloadNamespace().
